# How to properly save form data in Google App Engine

Tags: python, flask

I have an email form where I'm trying to save the user's email address to the database. The model looks like this:

```
class EmailForm(db.Model):                                                
  email_address = db.EmailProperty
```

I've been using a few tutorials like [this](http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-flask-on-google-app-engine.html) as a guide where the data from the form is saved like this:

```
title = form.title.data,
content = form.content.data
```

when I follow the same convention, writing

```
email = form.email_address.data
```

there is an error that the EmailProperty does not have a data attribute.

I'm new to Google App Engine but I haven't found an answer in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to use a Model as a Form, which are two different things.

You need another step

```
from flaskext import wtf
from flaskext.wtf import validators

class EmailModel(db.Model):
    email_address = db.EmailProperty

class EmailForm(wtf.Form):
    email = wtf.TextField('Email Address', validators=[validators.Email()])
```

Now, in your view you can use the form like so.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST']
def register():
    form = EmailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # This part saves the data from the form to the model.
        email_model = EmailModel(email_address = form.email.data)
        email.put()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Email

email_address = db.EmailProperty()

email_address = db.Email("larry@example.com")

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using the old db class, use instead ndb, just replace db for ndb (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit?ndplr=1&pli=1)
2. Use StringProperty instead EmailProperty, so..

   ```
   class UserEmail(ndb.Model):                                                
     email_address = ndb.StringProperty()
   ```
3. To put models in datastore, do this

   ```
   user = UserEmail(email_address='foobar@gmail.com')
   user.put()
   ```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I wanted to use NDB but I wasn't sure whether to use the StringProperty or EmailProperty.